# decrease the size of Material Navigation drawer-drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I'm using http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html

So, how we can decrease size of this drawer?

i mean this drawer size:

[image]

to the Telegram example(exactly like this):

[image]

Comment: By decreasing the width of the navigation drawer in your layout file maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the layout_width to required size

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```